# How to run an ansible-playbook with a passphrase-protected-ssh-private-key?

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have created an autoscaling group for Amazon `EC2` and I have added my public key when I created the AMI with `packer`, I can run ansible-playbook and ssh to the hosts.

But there is a problem when I run the playbook like this
`ansible-playbook load.yml` I am getting this message that I need to write my password

> Enter passphrase for key '/Users/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa':
> Enter passphrase
> for key '/Users/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa':
> Enter passphrase for key
> '/Users/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa':

The problem is it doesn't accept my password (I am sure I am typing my password correctly).

I found that I can send my password with `ask-pass` flag,  so I have changed my command to  `ansible-playbook load.yml --ask-pass` and I got some progress but again for some other task it asks for the password again and it didn't accept my password

```
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/hosts as an inventory source

 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************

TASK [ec2_instance_facts] ****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [add_host] **************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=xx.xxx.xx.xxx)
changed: [localhost] => (item=yy.yyy.yyy.yyy)

PLAY [instances] *************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Copy gatling.conf] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [xx.xxx.xx.xxx]
ok: [yy.yyy.yyy.yyy]
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/ccc/.ssh/id_rsa': Enter passphrase for key '/Users/ccc/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/ccc/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/ccc/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/ccc/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

If I don't use `ask-pass` flag even the task `[Copy gatling.conf]` doesn't complete and complaining about could not access the hosts. By adding the flag this part passes, but my next task again asks for pass.

How should I solve this issue? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I solved it by running `ssh-add` once and use it like if it's not password protected.

Answer (score 85):

In ansible There is no option to store passphrase-protected private key

For that we need to add the passphrase-protected private key in the ssh-agent

Start the ssh-agent in the background.

```
# eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Add SSH private key to the ssh-agent

```
# ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Now try running ansible-playbook and ssh to the hosts.

Comment: Best description for me

Comment: thanks a lot, it helped me quite a bit !

Comment: can this be added to the playbook in some way?

Comment: Could you explain how did that solved the issue? I mean what does starting the agent in the background really do with Ansible? Is it just caching the passphrase?

Answer (score 3):

Building up on @javeed-shakeel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51500802/2454732), I added the following lines to my `.bashrc`:

```
command -v ansible > /dev/null &&
    alias ansible='ssh-add -l > /dev/null || ssh-add 2> /dev/null && ansible'
command -v ansible-playbook > /dev/null &&
    alias ansible-playbook='ssh-add -l > /dev/null || ssh-add 2> /dev/null && ansible-playbook'
```

This will run `ssh-add` before `ansible(-playbook)` iff there was no key added to the ssh-agent, yet. This has the advantage that one does not need to run `ssh-add` by hand and one will be asked for the passphrase only if it is necessary.

Comment: I had to add the path of my private  key to the ssh-add command because it doesn't use the standard name `command -v ansible > /dev/null && alias ansible='ssh-add -l > /dev/null || ssh-add ~/.shh/name_of_private_key 2> /dev/null && ansible'`

Answer (score 0):

A **passphrase** is something else than a **password**. When ssh asks for a password, then you login as a user with a password that is checked by the computer you ssh into. It might be a company-wide password (AD, LDAP, etc.), or a local admin password.

A passphrase is used to encrypt the private key of your ssh key-pair. Typically the key-pair is generated with `ssh-keygen`, this command asks for a passphrase twice when you create your key-pair. That is for security, because when there is no passphrase on the private key, then anyone with a copy of the file can impersonate you! The passphrase is an added factor to the security.

`ssh-agent` is a program that creates a session for the use of your key-pair.

If you want to automate in GitLab with the use of an encrypted ssh key-pair this might help:

```
  ##
  ## Install ssh-agent if not already installed.
  ## (change apt-get to yum if you use an RPM-based image)
  ##
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'

  ##
  ## Run ssh-agent (on the Ansible control host)
  ##
  - eval $(ssh-agent)

  ##
  ## Create the SSH directory and give it the right permissions
  ##
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh

  ## Create a shell script that will echo the environment variable SSH_PASSPHRASE
  - echo 'echo $SSH_PASSPHRASE' > ~/.ssh/tmp && chmod 700 ~/.ssh/tmp
  ## If ssh-add needs a passphrase, it will read the passphrase from the current
  ## terminal if it was run from a terminal.  If ssh-add does not have a terminal
  ## associated with it but DISPLAY and SSH_ASKPASS are set, it will execute the
  ## program specified by SSH_ASKPASS and open an X11 window to read the
  ## passphrase.  This is particularly useful when calling ssh-add from a
  ## .xsession or related script. Setting DISPLAY=None drops the use of X11.

  ## Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
  ## We're using tr to fix line endings which makes ed25519 keys work
  ## without extra base64 encoding.
  ## https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/issues/1#note_48526556
  ##
 
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | DISPLAY=None SSH_ASKPASS=~/.ssh/tmp ssh-add -

  ##
  ## Use ssh-keyscan to scan the keys of your private server. Replace example.com
  ## with your own domain name. You can copy and repeat that command if you have
  ## more than one server to connect to.
  ##
  - ssh-keyscan example.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```