# SSH-key with passphrase , ansible git pull

Tags: git, ansible, ssh-keys

I have problem. ssh-key passphrase permission denied (using ansible)

I use ssh-agent 
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add /root/.ssh/new_rsa
enter passphrase

How debug this? I need git pull via ansible , using ssh-key and passphrase

```
ansible playbook : 
- hosts: testnew
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Git update
    git:
      key_file: /root/.ssh/new_rsa
      repo: git@bitbucket.org:Ads/ads.git
      dest: /path/
      accept_hostkey: yes
      remote: origin
      update: yes
      version: feature/out
    ignore_errors: yes

 "msg": "Failed to download remote objects and refs:  git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n"




ansible.cfg :
[defaults]
inventory=/etc/ansible/hosts
#transport = ssh
enable_task_debugger = False
host_key_checking = False
become_flags=-HE
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes -o ControlPath=/tmp/ssh-%r@%h:%p -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=30s
```

Comment: Hello Dmitri - I hope this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50277495/how-to-run-an-ansible-playbook-with-a-passphrase-protected-ssh-private-key

Comment: Can we see text output for `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` ?

Comment: direct connection ok